# Batch create a set of subfolders in several folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My goal is to create a set of folders with identical subfolders. I need one folder for every year since 1881, each year-folder should contain a folder per month, and each month-folder should contain a folder per day.

I have found a tool to create the folders for the years, my challenge now is to populate them with the subfolders. I want to do this on a Windows client computer, preferably without installing anything.

What I have been working on, is using the FOR and MD commands to do the job. Here's the code I have so far:

```
SET %g=*.*
FOR /d %var IN %path% DO MKDIR 01 02 03
```

Whenever I run this, I get this error:

> %path% was unexpected at this time

So, that is where I am stuch right now. I'd appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, read `HELP FOR` and then to begin with something, try this in a command line

```
  for /l %a in (1881,1,2012) do @echo %a
```

now you're wet already, add some spice

```
  for /l %a in (1881,1,2012) do @for /l %b in (1,1,12) do @echo %a-%b
```

and you're almost done

```
  for /l %a in (1881,1,2012) do @for /l %b in (1,1,12) do @for /l %c in (1,1,31) do @echo %a-%b-%c
```

the only thing left is to transform your `echo` into the appropiate `mkdir` and adding some incantation to translate it into a BAT file....

```
@echo off
pushd d:\dest
for /l %%a in (1881,1,2012) do (
  mkdir %%a
  pushd %%a
  for /l %%b in (1,1,12) do (
     mkdir %%b
     pushd %%b
     for /l %%c in (1,1,31) do (
       mkdir %%c
     )
     popd
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

but, be warned, this will grow extremely crazy!

Comment: No need for pushd/popd and mkdir only needed in inner-most loop: `mkdir d:\dest\%%a\%%b\%%c`

Answer (score 6):

Excuse me P.A. Your solution is right, I just couldn't resist the temptation to add some code to create the right number of days per month.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set m=0
for %%d in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set daysInMonth[!m!]=%%d
)
pushd d:\dest
for /L %%y in (1881,1,2012) do (
   mkdir %%y
   pushd %%y
   for /L %%m in (1,1,12) do (
      mkdir %%m
      pushd %%m
      set days=!daysInMonth[%%m]!
      if %%m == 2 (
         set /A yMod4=%%y %% 4, yMod100=%%y %% 100, yMod400=%%y %% 400
         if !yMod4! == 0 (
            set /A days+=1
            if !yMod100! == 0 if not !yMod400! == 0 (
               set /A days-=1
            )
         )
      )
      for /L %%d in (1,1,!days!) do (
         mkdir %%d
      )
      popd
   )
   popd
)
popd
```

Previous code add 1 day to February in leap years, that is, if the year is divisible by 4, but at centurial years only if it is also divisible by 400. 1600 and 2000 were leap years, but 1700, 1800 and 1900 were not.

Comment: +1 for an _always_ correct answer, but do you excpect that one of your leap year exceptions will ever be used?

Comment: @jeb: Well, the OP requires to create year folders for 1900 and 2000. Also, think about this: Batch files were invented more than 30 years ago and we are here using them! So, who knows for the 2100? :)

Comment: +1 good solution: some optimization/simplification - Computation of days in month can be reduced to `set /a "days=daysInMonth[%%m]+(^!(%%m-2)&^!(%%y%%4)&(^!^!(%%y%%100)|^!(%%y%%400)))"`. No need for pushd and intermediate mkdir. Simply use this in inner most loop: `for /L %%d in (1,1,!days!) do mkdir d:\dest\%%y\%%m\%%d`.